# JQuery UI draggable to adjust the divs size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have two divs, and I want them to share the 100% of the width of their parent. I also have a small divider in between, which allows them do dynamically resize them. But the total area must remain same. I have uploaded my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/aRQ7a/

However, because I decrease the size of the previous one, the slider goes back even further, they are not aligned properly. How can I fix this? My code is the below:

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
div {
    display: inline-flex;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
#part1 {
    width: 47%;
    background-color: red;
}
#part2 {
    width: 47%;
    background-color: green;
}
.divider {
    width: 5%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="part1"></div>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div id="part2"></div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    var p1 = parseInt($("#part1").css("width"));
    var p2 = parseInt($("#part2").css("width"));

    $(".divider").draggable({
        axis: "x",
        containment: "parent",
        scroll: false,
        start: function(){
            p1 = parseInt($("#part1").css("width"));
            p2 = parseInt($("#part2").css("width"));
        },
        drag: function (event,  ui) {
            var a = parseInt($(this).css("left"));
            $(this).prev().css("width", p1 +  a);
            $(this).next().css("width", p2 -  a);            
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is it ok to use absolute positioning?

Comment: @popnoodles Why wouldn't it be ok? I mean what would be a problem if absolutely positioned? I'm not so familiar with positioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working demo http://jsfiddle.net/aRQ7a/2/

The problem was that when you dragged the divider, both the mouse and #part1 were affecting its position which is why it moved 2x the distance dragged. By setting that to position absolutely, we can stop it being affected by anything except the mouse.

By positioning #part2 to right:0, all we then need to do is get its width correct.

```
$(function () {
    var p1 = parseInt($("#part1").width());
    var p2 = parseInt($("#part2").width());

    $(".divider").draggable({
        axis: "x",
        containment: "parent",
        scroll: false,
        drag: function () {
            var a = parseInt($(this).position().left);
            $("#part1").css({width:a});
            $("#part2").css({width:p1 + p2 -a });
        }
    });
});
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
div {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 300px;
}
#part1 {
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    width: 47%;
    background-color: red;
}
#part2 {
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    width: 47%;
    background-color: green;
}
.divider {
    width: 5%;
    position:absolute;
    left: 47%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Just one other thing. The divider is 5% width, but 2 x 47% leaves 6%. You may want this behavior, I can't guess that.

Comment: Also you can use `.width()` to get and set widths, rather than `.css()`

Comment: Close, but there is a white fringe to the divider which changes as you move it.

Comment: @popnoodles can it be done in vertical too? I tried but it did not work. I just changed the `left` to `top` and `width` to `height`

Comment: @popnoodles Sorry, I forgot to change the axis from x to y. It works perfectly now.

Comment: @LeeTaylor The white fringe was there in the original because the divider size is less than the gap left by 2*47%. I saw this but it's not for me to decide what Mustafa wanted with regards to that.

Answer (score 2):

Check this

http://jsfiddle.net/aRQ7a/3/

js

```
$(function () {
    var p1 = parseInt($("#part1").css("width"));
    var p2 = parseInt($("#part2").css("width"));
    var fullWidth= $('body').width();
    var initialPos = parseInt($(".divider").css("left"));
    $(".divider").draggable({
        axis: "x",
        containment: "parent",
        scroll: false,
        drag: function () {
            var a = parseInt($(this).css("left"));

            $("#part1").css("width", a);
            $("#part2").css("width", fullWidth-a);

        }
    });
});
```

css

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
div {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 300px;
}
#part1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 47%;
    background-color: red;
}
#part2 {
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    width: 47%;
    background-color: green;
}
.divider {
    width: 5%;
    position:absolute;
    left: 47%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: +1 but please explain why yours works and the original didn't !

Comment: because in original. the css is not proper, and in JS the formula in drag function is different. to divide the full width of parent , first half will get the left value of divider and the second half will get the remaining i.e fullwidth - left value of divider.